# Ist „die tosende Minna“ ein Synonym für die Spülmaschine?

Tags: phrase, idiom

Die Mitglieder der älteren Generation in meiner Familie nennen die Spülmaschine manchmal *die tosende Minna*. Als ich heute googeln wollte, wo dieser Spruch eigentlich herkommt, bekam ich kein einziges Suchergebnis. Jetzt frage ich mich, ob meine Familie diese Phrase einfach erfunden hat, oder ob es tatsächlich ein allgemein bekanntes Synonym für die Spülmaschine ist – und wenn ja, wo kommt es her?

Comment: Nicht zu verwechseln mit der [grünen Minna](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.polizeihistorischesammlung-paul.de%2Fwissenswertes%2FMinna%2Fdie_gruene_minna.htm&rct=j&q=gr%C3%BCne%20Minna&ei=FYVkTufsBMWa-gaf4pX0CQ&usg=AFQjCNFVHy5730PKZZMPkAR9dPL6H01zEQ&cad=rja) ;)

Comment: Nie gehört, und wird wohl, wegen immer leiseren Maschinen, auch in Kürze aussterben. :)

Comment: Ich kenne das auch, allerdings nicht zusammen mit "tosend" ...

Comment: I like that expression for a Spülmaschine.

Comment: Das scheint ganz individueller Sprachgebrauch zu sein, typisch für Gruppen. Glaube, in der Linguistik gibt es dafür auch einen speziellen Begriff.Schüler einer Klasse, Matrosen auf einen Schiff, Mitglieder eines Vereins etc entwickeln schnell Ausdrücke, die nur in ihrem Kreis verständlich sind.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Früher bezeichnete man eine Hausangestellte auch *Minna*, eine Kurzform des damals gebräuchlichen weiblichen Vornamens *Wilhelmine*<sup>([Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Minna_Hausangestellte_Polizeiwagen))</sup>.

Mit zunehmender Verbreitung von Haushaltsmaschinen wurden und werden zum Teil auch heute noch diese Geräte scherzhaft als *Minna* bezeichnet. Insbesondere eine Waschmaschine und weniger auch für eine Spülmaschine wird so genannt<sup>([Die Zeit](http://www.zeit.de/1996/52/Kommet_ihr_Maenner_))</sup>. Ein Beispiel, wie *Minna* sogar  Markennamen für eine Küchenmaschine wurde, findet sich bei [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minna_%28K%C3%BCchenmaschine%29).

Answer (score 13):

Ich habe zwar den Ausdruck noch nie gehört, aber es spricht einiges dafür, dass er früher scherzhaft für Spülmaschine verwendet wurde.

*Minna* nannte man früher die **Hausmädchen** wohlhabender Familien. Es gibt eine Redewendung, die heute noch verwendet wird: *jemanden zur Minna machen.* Das bedeutet, jemanden mit starken Worten zurechtzuweisen oder zu beschimpfen.

Es gibt ein Buch von einem gewissen Dr. Freimund Pfeiffer aus dem Jahr 1835, das ein [Gedicht mit dem Titel *Minna*](http://books.google.de/books?id=yU87AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA34&dq=tosend%20minna&hl=de&ei=_cxjTuGbOcnk4QTP08SdCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) enthält. Das Gedicht enthält die Zeilen

> Aus des Nordes wildem Tosen
>   Minna! mir entgegenschallt.

Vielleicht ist das bloß ein Zufall; es könnte allerdings auch der Urspung des Wortspiels *tosende Minna* sein.

Comment: +1 für "zur Minna machen"

Answer (score 0):

Ich kenne auch den Ausdruck "Minna" für ein Geschirrspülmaschine. Ist abgeleitet von veraltet für Waschweib, bzw. küchenhilfe.